# Writing a constructor of a class that extends an ArrayList

Tags: java, constructor

This is the signature of my class:

```java
public class Constraint extends ArrayList<Interval> {
    // ...
}
```

the other class Interval:

```
public class Interval {
    // ...
}
```

has two `int`s, `first` and `last`

Constructor:

```
public Interval(int first, int last) { 
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
}
```

A method that returns the union of two Intervals or more but should be of Constraint type:

```
 public Constraint union(Interval interval) {
     Interval a = new Interval(first, end);
     int l = 0;
     int max = 0;
     // Interval result = new Interval(l, max);
     l = (a.first < interval.end) ? a.first : interval.end;
     max = (a.end > interval.end) ? a.end : interval.end;
     return new Interval(l, max); 
     // the return here will return a new interval of type Interval but
     // the method that I'm suppose to write should return something of
     // type Constraint
}
```

My main issue is: how can I write the following constructor?

```
 public Constraint(Collection<Interval> collection) throws  NullPointerException {
    // if the collection is empty, I have to write something like this: 
    if (collection == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("collection is empty");
    }
    // ...
}
```

Any help on how I should write the constructor of the class Constraint is  really appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I've fixed your formatting. Please take care of that yourself next time. The question seems to have a lot of unrelated code. What is that `union` method for when you're struggling with the `Constraint` constructor? Please read [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, what's wrong with the constructor as you have it?

Answer (score 1):

You have stumbled upon a deficiency of Java: the call to `super()` must be the first call in your constructor, so you are not allowed to precede it with code that checks against null. There is no good reason for this limitation, it is just the way java is. A flaw in the language.  (If you learn Scala you will see that it totally did not have to be this way.)

So, the solution is to do the null-check **in the same statement as** the call to `super`.  The following should accomplish this:

```
public Constraint( Collection<Interval> collection ) 
{
    super( Objects.requireNonNull( collection ) );
}
```

If your version of java does not have `Objects.requireNonNull()` you can code a private static function yourself which checks the collection for nullity, throws if `null`, or returns the collection as-is if not `null`.